# Excel 2010 solver not working properly

Tags: excel, solver

I'm trying to set up a system of equations which reference cells. I'm trying to get the left side of each equation to equal the right side, by changing certain variable cells.

To cut to the chase, solver was returning that there was no solution. There is certainly a solution as this is an established set of equations.

On looking into it, I removed constraints until I found the problem; excel solver was not attempting to use negative numbers for the inputs to solve the equation. I simplified to one constraint that could be solved by making one input -1 and leaving everything else the same, and it still returned no results, where every other constraint could be met fine.

I'm not sure if there is a reason why excel is not trying to use negative numbers. I did not include an objective in the solver function because it was not necessary, but it still worked well with other constraints.

I'm using excel 2010. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the setting "Make Unconstrained Variables Non-Negative":

[image]

If turned on variables are restricted to be positive.